# Hermitean conjugate of spinor product

Tags: supersymmetry, spinors

Consider spinors $\psi_\alpha$ in the $(0,1/2)$ rep and $\bar{\psi}_{\dot{\alpha}}$ in the $(1/2,0)$ rep. I'm using notation from the [following notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0101055). All we will need is the totally antisymmetric 2x2 tensors $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta}=\epsilon^{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}$, for which $\epsilon^{12} = 1$. These tensors are used to lower and raise spinor indices, $\psi^\alpha = \epsilon^{\alpha\beta}\psi_\beta$, $\bar{\psi}^{\dot{\alpha}}=\epsilon^{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}\bar{\psi_{\dot{\beta}}}$

Dotted indices are contracted lower left to upper right, and for undotted, upper left to lower right. I have then a problem with the hermitean conjugate. I don't understand if it is a matter of definition, but if so the definition is pretty strange to me, so I must be doing something wrong. My intuition would be that the hermitean conjugate should reduce to the complex conjugate when applied on numbers for the definition to be meaningful. Consider then the scalar product $\psi\chi$ which is a number :

$$(\psi\chi)^\dagger =(\psi^a\chi_a)^\dagger= (\psi_a\epsilon^{ba}\chi_b)^\dagger = (\psi_a\epsilon^{ba}\chi_b)^*=\psi_a^*\epsilon^{ba}\chi_b^*=\bar{\psi}_\dot{a}\epsilon^{\dot{b}\dot{a}}\bar{\chi}_\dot{b}=-\bar{\psi}_\dot{a}\epsilon^{\dot{a}\dot{b}}\bar{\chi}_\dot{b}=-\bar{\psi}_\dot{a}\bar{\chi}^{\dot{a}}=-\bar{\psi}\bar{\chi}$$

Where I used that $\epsilon^{ab}=\epsilon^{\dot{a}\dot{b}}$, and the fact that $\psi_a^*$ transforms as a dotted spinor.

Now what I obtain has an extra minus sign compared to the source I linked, and to most other sources I can come up with. However, this results seems to me unavoidable with the definitions I used, and if we want to preserve the fact that the hermitean conjugate acting on number should be the complex conjugate. Can anybody point to me my mistake ? I am unable to see at which step I have made an error. I suspect it is something that has to do with the fact that spinors anticommute, but I can't see where.

Another possibility is from the fact that we contract undotted and dotted indices in a different way. If we choose the same contraction convention for both, then the problem vanishes. However I think this contraction convention is used everywhere, so this is probably not it.

Comment: The quantity $\psi \chi$ isn't a "number", it's just a product of two Grassmann numbers.

Comment: Also, the specific problem appears to be that Hermitian conjugation is defined to reverse the order of Grassmann numbers, but you didn't account for this.

Comment: I was suspecting there may be a definition problem, but I don't get exactly what you mean. Isn't hermitean conjugation defined to act on a single element ? Like we can hermitean conjugate operators, and then we prove that hermitean conjugation of a product reverses the order. Also, what is the product of two grassman numbers if it isn't a number ? Classically at least, it seems to me that it has all the properties of a normal "number".

Comment: Another comment it seems that the convetional definition is taken so $(\psi\chi)^\dagger=\chi^\dagger\psi^\dagger$ holds, so that it is the same identity we have with hermitean product of bosonic quantities. However, when we prove this identity with bosonic quantities, there is an anticommutation of the two variables, such that if we repeat the same proof with fermionic quantities, we should get $(\psi\chi)^\dagger=-\chi^\dagger\psi^\dagger$, which is exactly the proof I showed. So I think I did take into account the "reversing order" inside my proof. But there may be a definition I dont get

Comment: It's not a number though, the product of two Grassmann numbers is the analogue of a rank 2 differential form, which is very different from a scalar, even if does happen to commute via wedge products.

Comment: Also, I just don't see what's wrong with the conventional definition! A Grassmann number isn't the same thing as a bosonic operator, it's a new thing. So we get to make new definitions for it -- you don't need to "prove" a definition. And the conventional definitions were chosen to make things come out nice, like avoiding the extra minus sign you have.

Comment: It's just I don't see how we get to define how the hermitean product acts on a product of grassman variables. In the bosonic case, you define how the hermitean product acts on an operator, you then prove that when acting on a product of operators reverses the order. For matrices for example, the hermitean conjugate is transposing and taking the complex conjugate (albeit in an orthonormal basis), from which I can then prove the property on the product. I understand my "number" argument is wrong, but then what is the right definition of hermitean product here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105951/discussion-between-frotaur-and-knzhou).